# How do I make meta tags work with Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, meta-tags

I am having issues with meta tags on Wordpress. For some reason, none of them show up when I am testing them, I am pretty sure I used the code correctly. I will put my code below. I put the code in the "header.php" file under Appearance > Theme Editor in Wordpress.

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://twobrake.xyz" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="TwoBrake" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="TwoBrake" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://twobrake.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/cropped-cropped-Discord-Main-PFP.png" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
</head>
```

Comment: Are you certain you are editting the correct theme? Are you sure you are editting the correct file? If so, can it be a caching problem?

Comment: A good way to check for me to see if it's caching, because it looks like you are adding the meta tags to the correct file, is to add a redirect meta.  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://somesite.com'" />`.  If it does not redirect, check it again in incognito mode, and it it redirects you are in the right place and it's definitely caching.  If it doesn't redirect in incognito mode then the theme are using holds the `<head>` tag elsewhere and you just need to find out where. 
`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be redirecting, I am currently using the Wordpress plain text theme.